# Can I use same Self signed certificate for different servers?

Tags: android, ssl, ssl-certificate, sslcontext

I am developing an Android App and I have different servers (ex: server.example1.com, server.example2.com, server.example3.com) and I do not know if I can use the same Self Signed Certificate in my App or not?

Can anybody explain to me what it the right thing to do?
Should I not use Self Signed Certificate pinned on my App at all or...?